# Motherboard: ASUS TUF B450M-PRO II wol does not work

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have made a mistake and bought a cheap motherboard. Now I have an issue with it. It is an ASUS TUF B450M-PRO II. It is working fine, but I cannot get wol configured properly to wake from hibernation. When I power on the computer manually I can hibernate it through the network, but I cannot wake it up again.

I have updated the bios to the latest version (2021 March 21), enabled network stack, wol on PCI-E, power management, but the issue remained.

Is there anyone with a similar problem? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across `ethtool`, which helped me to solve it:

> man /usr/sbin/ethtool

When I run it on eth0:

> /usr/sbin/ethtool eth0

it turned out that wol was off. Then to enable it:

> /usr/sbin/ethtool -s  eth0 wol g

After this, I could power on/off the computer from the network.

Comment: PS: you can accept your own answers after a while.